# OutOfMemory exception on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

When I try to deploy a war which is more than 50mb, Tomcat encounters OutOfMemory exception. I've tried to add CATALINA_OPTS and increased heap size but yet not working. 
Opts used - Xms=512M - Xmx=1024M
This is on Eclipse, however I've tried with Intellij with Tomcat configuration, with same JVM Opts, still gives me OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: 1G is not a huge amount of memory. Without knowing what your `.war` does it's very hard to say if it needs more. But it seems like it does...

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the web.xml of the manager application (for instance it could be under /tomcat7/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml.
- Increase the max-file-size and max-request-size: 50mb

  ```
  <multipart-config>

  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>

  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>

  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>

  </multipart-config>
  ```